# Vanity URL - Additional /

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, structure

I've been trying to create a .htaccess vanity URL for a specific page/url structure but have been unable to get it working.

The current URL looks like this:

```
    domain.com/test/support/article/?id=10
```

And I want to change it too:

```
    domain.com/test/support/article/id/10
```

However, no matter what I set up in he .htaccess, it doesn't seem to work.

I've tried a few variations of the following:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^id/(\d+)*$ .article/?id=$1
```

Any idea why this wouldn't be working?

Answer (score 0):

Are you encountering any issues with it not working?

Might want to take a look at RewriteMap http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap